# How to integrate Gnosis Wallet into my Dapp?

Tags: solidity, web3js, metamask, gnosis-safe

My dApp already supports MetaMask, but does anyone have any helpful documentation that allows for my users to connect using a Gnosis Safe wallet as well?

As of now, I have Wallet Connect integrated, and on my Gnosis Safe App on my phone it shows that I'm connected, but it doesn't seem to be registering on my dApp.

Any links would be super helpful, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I think this article could help you https://blog.gnosis.pm/turn-your-dapp-into-a-gnosis-safe-app-in-5-minutes-5cdb33a1cd46

There are a couple of options how to integrate Gnosis Safe with dApp. It depends how you integrated metamask.

Comment: Broken Link, please replace